# Qt - Close subMenu with signal/slot

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qmainwindow

I have a Qt main window where I call another window, actually a kind of submenu wich contains parameters for the first one; here is a part of this main window :

```
void Ui_MainWindow::createSignals()
{ 
  connect(actionDisk_galaxy, SIGNAL(triggered()), this,  SLOT(ICMenu()));
}

void Ui_MainWindow::ICMenu()
{
qmenu = new QMainWindow;
DiskMenu = new Ui_DiskGalMenu;
DiskMenu->setupUi(qmenu,this);
setInitialDiskMenuPosition(qmenu, this);
qmenu->show();
}
```

As you can see, I call another QMainwindow ("`qmenu`"); here's the code of this new window (whose type is "`Ui_DiskGalMenu`"):

```
void Ui_DiskGalMenu::createMenuSignals()
{
  connect(pushButton_4, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(closeMenu()));       
}

void Ui_DiskGalMenu::closeMenu()
{  
close(true);
}
```

After setting parameters in this sub-menu, I would like to close it with a pushButton (here "`pushButton_4`").

My problem is that when I click on "pushButton_4", this window doesn't close.

I have also tried to reimplement `closeEvent` but without success.

Answer (score 0):

This function call looks like a mistake:

```
close(true);
```

QWidget::close() doesn't take any parameters. So what you're doing here, is call the close(int) function of the C library (for closing file descriptors.) `bool` is implicitly converted to `int`, so you end up with this call:

```
::close(1);
```

Which is (probably) closing `stderr`.

You can see what's happening if you change the above to:

```
this->close(true);
```

You should get a compilation error since no such function exists. So the correct call would have been:

```
this->close();
```

However, QWidget::close() is already a slot, so you don't need the Ui_DiskGalMenu::closeMenu() function at all. All you need is connect to the close() slot to begin with:

```
connect(actionDisk_galaxy, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));
```

If you need to do more stuff when the window closes, you can override closeEvent() which will be called before the window gets closed.